# C# WIA ADF Has next page

Tags: c#, wia, image-scanner

I have created a WIA Wrapper, which I beleive will be usefull for some people.
It's still in development stages, but it all works besides the fact that the HasNextPage method does not work. I have taken the code from a lot of different sources. But basically, in my code, the WIA.Properties does not change if there is no pages left in the ADF so it always thinks there is another page? I could do a sloppy (try catch if no paper error, but thats very sloppy)

Any ideas?

heres my code:

ps - i dont mind critisism on coding standards, please comment on anything that'll make me a better programmer :)

(There are a few lines of code I have that are there to try and debug it) The main problem is, no matter what I do the Document Handling Status does not change

```
public struct PageSize
{
    public double Height;
    public double Width;

    public PageSize(double height, double width)
    {
        this.Height = height;
        this.Width = width;
    }
}

class WIA_PROPERTIES
{
    public const uint WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS = 1024;
    public const uint WIA_DIP_FIRST = 2;
    public const uint WIA_DPA_FIRST  =  WIA_DIP_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS;
    public const uint WIA_DPC_FIRST  = WIA_DPA_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS;
    //
    // Scanner only device properties (DPS)
    //
    public const uint WIA_DPS_FIRST    =                      WIA_DPC_FIRST + WIA_RESERVED_FOR_NEW_PROPS;
    public const uint WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS  =     WIA_DPS_FIRST + 13;
    public const uint WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT  =     WIA_DPS_FIRST + 14;
}



public class WiaWrapper
{

    //Image Filenames
    const string wiaFormatBMP = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    const string wiaFormatPNG = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    const string wiaFormatGIF = "{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    const string wiaFormatJPEG = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    const string wiaFormatTIFF = "{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";

    //Standard Page Sizes
    public PageSize A3 = new PageSize(16.5, 11.7);
    public PageSize A4 = new PageSize(11.7, 8.3);
    public PageSize A5 = new PageSize(8.3, 5.8);
    public PageSize A6 = new PageSize(5.8, 4.1);

    public string DeviceID;

    #region Setup/select Scanner

    /// <summary>
    /// Select Scanner.
    /// If you need to save the Scanner, Save WiaWrapper.DeviceID
    /// </summary>
    public void SelectScanner()
    {
        WIA.CommonDialog wiaDiag = new WIA.CommonDialog();

        try
        {
            Device d = wiaDiag.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, true, false);
            if (d != null)
            {
                DeviceID = d.DeviceID;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error, Is a scanner chosen?");
        }

        throw new Exception("No Device Selected");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Connect to Scanning Device
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceID"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Device Connect()
    {
        Device WiaDev = null;

        DeviceManager manager = new DeviceManager();

        //Iterate through each Device until correct Device found
        foreach (DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
        {
            if (info.DeviceID == DeviceID)
            {
                WIA.Properties infoprop = info.Properties;

                WiaDev = info.Connect();
                return WiaDev;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Scanner not found - Is it setup in DeviceID?");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Scanning utilities - hasMorePages, SetupPageSize, SetupADF, DeleteFile

    /// <summary>
    /// Check to see if ADF has more pages loaded
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wia"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool HasMorePages(Device wia)
    {

        //determine if there are any more pages waiting
        Property documentHandlingSelect = null;
        Property documentHandlingStatus = null;

        string test = string.Empty;

        foreach (Property prop in wia.Properties)
        {
            string propername = prop.Name;
            string propvalue = prop.get_Value().ToString();

            test += propername + " " + propvalue + "<br>";

            if (prop.PropertyID == WIA_PROPERTIES.WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT)
                documentHandlingSelect = prop;
            if (prop.PropertyID == WIA_PROPERTIES.WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_STATUS)
                documentHandlingStatus = prop;
        }

        if ((Convert.ToUInt32(documentHandlingSelect.get_Value()) & 0x00000001) != 0)
        {
            return ((Convert.ToUInt32(documentHandlingStatus.get_Value()) & 0x00000001) != 0);
        }

        string tester = test;

        return false;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Setup Page Size
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wia"></param>
    private void SetupPageSize(Device wia, bool rotatePage, PageSize pageSize, int DPI, WIA.Item item)
    {

        //Setup Page Size Property
        foreach (WIA.Property itemProperty in item.Properties)
        {

            if (itemProperty.Name.Equals("Horizontal Resolution"))
            {
                ((IProperty)itemProperty).set_Value(DPI);
            }
            else if (itemProperty.Name.Equals("Vertical Resolution"))
            {
                ((IProperty)itemProperty).set_Value(DPI);
            }
            else if (itemProperty.Name.Equals("Horizontal Extent"))
            {

                double extent = DPI * pageSize.Height;

                if (rotatePage)
                {
                    extent = DPI * pageSize.Width;
                }


                ((IProperty)itemProperty).set_Value(extent);


            }
            else if (itemProperty.Name.Equals("Vertical Extent"))
            {
                double extent = DPI * pageSize.Width;

                if (rotatePage)
                {
                    extent = pageSize.Height * DPI;
                }


                ((IProperty)itemProperty).set_Value(extent);
            }

        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Setup device to Use ADF if required
    /// </summary>
    private void SetupADF(Device wia, bool duplex)
    {
        string adf = string.Empty;

        foreach (WIA.Property deviceProperty in wia.Properties)
        {
            adf += deviceProperty.Name + "<br>";
            if (deviceProperty.Name == "Document Handling Select") //or PropertyID == 3088
            {
                int value = duplex ? 0x004 : 0x001;
                deviceProperty.set_Value(value);
            }

        }

    }

    private void Delete_File(string filename)
    {
        //Overwrite File
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            //file exists, delete it
            File.Delete(filename);
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region Scan Page - Main Public Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Scan Page,
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wia">Connected Device</param>
    /// <param name="pageSize">Page Size. A4, A3, A2 Etc</param>
    /// <param name="RotatePage">Rotation of page while scanning</param>
    public void Scan(PageSize pageSize, bool rotatePage, int DPI, string filepath, bool useAdf, bool duplex)
    {
        int pages = 0;
        bool hasMorePages = false;

        WIA.CommonDialog WiaCommonDialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();

        try
        {
            do
            {
                //Connect to Device
                Device wia = Connect();
                WIA.Item item = wia.Items[1] as WIA.Item;

                //Setup ADF
                if ((useAdf) || (duplex))
                    SetupADF(wia, duplex);

                //Setup Page Size
                SetupPageSize(wia, rotatePage, pageSize, DPI,item);

                WIA.ImageFile imgFile = null;
                WIA.ImageFile imgFile_duplex = null; //if duplex is setup, this will be back page


                imgFile = (ImageFile)WiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, wiaFormatJPEG, false);

                //If duplex page, get back page now.
                if (duplex)
                {
                    imgFile_duplex = (ImageFile)WiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, wiaFormatJPEG, false);
                }

                string varImageFileName = filepath + "\\Scanned-" + pages.ToString() + ".jpg";
                Delete_File(varImageFileName); //if file already exists. delete it.
                imgFile.SaveFile(varImageFileName);

                string varImageFileName_duplex; 

                if (duplex)
                {
                    varImageFileName_duplex = filepath + "\\Scanned-" + pages++.ToString() + ".jpg";
                    Delete_File(varImageFileName_duplex); //if file already exists. delete it.
                    imgFile_duplex.SaveFile(varImageFileName);
                }

                //Check with scanner to see if there are more pages.
                if (useAdf || duplex)
                {
                    hasMorePages = HasMorePages(wia);
                    pages++;
                }

            }
            while (hasMorePages);
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(CheckError((uint)ex.ErrorCode));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now beleive it is my scanner hardware (or driver) problem. I am uysing a Ricoh Aficio IS330DC.

The work around I did was put a Try/catch block and if exception is Out Of Paper then finish.

It works.